# Does certbot mask apache2?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

I recently ran a certbot command using --webroot on a server. Everything worked fine for 8+ hours.

This morning my frontend went down. Upon investigation I discovered that the apache2 service was down. It was masked for some reason so I unmasked it. It restarted but did not work. I tried to run a configtest but apache2ctl was not found. I ran sudo apt install apache2. Now everything is working again.

However I need to figure out the root cause of this issue and I cannot find anything in the logs or from searching. My guess is this was caused by certbot but I need to confirm that. Does anyone have any insight here?

Ubuntu 18, apache2, certbot via snap

Thank you

Comment: Read your package manager logs (I think, `/var/log/dpkg.log*`, `/var/log/apt/*` or something like that). It is more likey someone (including you) were installing something that was required removal of apache. And no, certbot itself has no such requirement.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. It looks like `startup packages remove` is the culprit here. I'm not entirely sure how this process works but I will do some investigating.